# Is it possible to recover files on NTFS after writing to the same directory?

Tags: windows, pdf, filesystems, data-recovery, ntfs

I've accidentally deleted a couple of `.tex` and `.pdf` files. The files were stored under `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\notes` on my laptop's SSD. I'm using a Windows 11 Pro. It seems like this happened about a month ago or less.

I've since added and removed files on `Desktop`, and it's only now that I noticed they were deleted. I'm trying to figure out how NTFS might have dealt with them and whether it's viable to try to recover them (using software like R-Studio).

In particular, I'm wondering the following: if I delete files and write new files on `Desktop`, does that automatically mean that the previous files will be overwritten by the new files? In other words, will the new files take their "place"?

If this is the case, I don't see any way to recover my files. If it isn't, where does NTFS store new files in such a situation - does it simply insert them in the first free block of memory?

Edit: Added info about OS.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the (secret) operating system used. On a legacy system like Windows XP without TRIM support your data will persist until the operating system issues a write command to a sector number that was occupied by your deleted data before. In all other cases read the given answers.

Comment: I believe it's worth mentioning that the question in the body asks the opposite of what is in the title. A "no" to the title could be a "yes" to the body and vice versa. 
It's why I was a little confused by u1686_grawity's answer at first...

Comment: But you are sure the files are not in the trash bin, right?

Comment: Yes, @Dubu. The files were not in the trash bin.

Comment: How is that, @Opifex? I wanted to ask a question about deleting files from `Desktop` and adding new files to `Desktop` and whether this affects the recovery of the deleted files. Any suggestions to make the title clearer?

Comment: @nocomment body asks "Are my old files overwritten by new ones?", title asks "Can I still recover them?". Those are, depending on the details, two very different questions with potentially different answers.

Comment: This comment is everyone's friendly daily reminder that the tagline of [the site's chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) is _"You have backups, right?"_ (± 'recent', 'tested', 'working', 'independent' 'differently-located' too)

Comment: Have you tried opening properties of the `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\notes` directory and seeing if Windows has any previous versions of the directory that may still contain the files?

I find the previous versions very hit-or-miss (usually when I want something more miss than hit).

I hope you have better luck than I usually do!

Comment: @Bja That's a good idea for anybody to try if they have the same issue. Unfortunately, I deleted the folder `notes` itself and `Desktop` had no previous versions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> In particular, I'm wondering the following: if I delete files and write new files on Desktop, does that automatically mean that the previous files will be overwritten by the new files? In other words, will the new files take their "place"?

No; at least generally not because directories "contain" files in the sense you're assuming. Directories aren't containers – they're little more than **lists** of files and they don't control the actual data allocations.

(Sometimes filesystems *try* to keep files from the same directory "near" each other, but that's a best-effort performance optimization at most – it's not actually the function of a directory.)

> where does NTFS store new files in such a situation - does it simply insert them in the first free block of memory?

Filesystems don't do that; they try to do the exact opposite and spread new allocations around, so that files would have some space to grow in size – doing so avoids fragmentation.

So if you create a new file in the same directory on NTFS, it has a pretty low chance of overwriting *any* deleted file, much less a file in the same directory.

There are third-party "defrag" tools that will show you a file's location graphically (not physical location, but in terms of logical clusters), and `fsutil file queryExtents` will do the same in console – the `LCN` column is the cluster number within the partition.

---

To clarify: My answer is about how the filesystem maps file positions to disk logical sectors, whereas the other two answers are about how the disk's firmware maps logical sectors to physical sectors.

The latter is generally invisible to the OS; even though there's a lot happening inside an SSD, it nevertheless presents a "stable" linear view of logical sectors to the OS. (Once a logical sector has been overwritten, even if its old data still physically lingers around, there's no command for OS to access it: all it sees is the "current" version of that logical sector.)

harrymc makes a good point, however, that SSDs have TRIM – a command used by the OS to immediately "discard" specific logical sectors, and which can pretty much be considered to be "overwrite with zeros". Because Windows issues TRIM immediately after a file is deleted (and because most SSDs treat TRIM as an immediate discard), the result is that as soon as you delete a file, the logical sectors corresponding to it **immediately** become empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it now makes a lot of sense. With what @harrymc said about defragmentation over 30 days, it's very unlikely that there are impartial data left. I'm curious though, do you have any suggestions for learning more about data storage and filesystems?

Comment: @nocomment: What harrymc said actually happens at a lower layer, **below** the filesystem. The internal structure of an SSD is completely invisible to the OS – as far as the computer sees, once something was written to logical sector 123, then that data stays in logical sector 123 until a) overwritten or b) discarded using TRIM. (Yes, the _physical_ sectors may be new, and old data may linger until the SSD does maintenance, but at that point it is already inaccessible to any tools running on the computer itself.)

Comment: @nocomment: But ultimately their point is correct, that if the old file's logical sectors have been freed _and NTFS has issued the 'TRIM' command on them_, then those logical sectors became practically unrecoverable at that point already – even if TRIM isn't required to immediately discard the data (it just tells the SSD that it _may_ do so), in practice most SSDs throw it away instantly. Therefore as soon as the file is deleted it's already unrecoverable.

Answer (score 8):

An SSD works very different than an HDD, since it does some
somewhat contradictory operations :

- Wear leveling attempts to write data in empty blocks, since this
  reduces the number of operations on the disk
- Garbage collection attempts to consolidate partially written
  blocks in one block
- [TRIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28computing%29)
  is used to erase a block when its data is deleted and it
  becomes totally empty.

Since this operation happened about a month ago, the firmware
had more than enough time to move data around. Blocks which
were deleted were trimmed and their data no longer exists,
and partial blocks were likely copied and their space was
trimmed.

Your chances of recuperating any such data on an SSD are
very low.
You could of course still try, and might even find some of the
data, but truly I don't think this is worth the bother.
Try perhaps to find the files in old backups.

Answer (score 2):

SSDs do not have a physical structure like a HDD.  Also TRIM is normally enable to set out where new files should be written. This could include (not necessarily) where the files were that you deleted.

Actual Trim operation to assist you:

> SSDs use a process called trimming to periodically erase blocks of
> data that are no longer in use. However, the actual removal of trimmed
> data happens through a complex process that determines when it takes
> place.
>
> Trimming not only frees up space on the drive but also helps the SSD
> perform better and last longer.

Please see:

[Trim explained](https://www.techspot.com/article/2600-ssd-trimming-explained/)

So it is very unlikely that you could recover such files. I would say "gone"

A quick look at Recuva on an SSD suggests it is just a matter of luck whether you can recover the files.

So overall:  Probably (90% or greater) the files are gone.

Comment: You might end up lucky, though, depending on the usage of the SSD and how aggressive the system is in its use of the TRIM command. I've been able to recover files deleted from an SSD more than a year prior to running Recuva on it. If the files were deleted a month ago or less, the chances of recovery are a lot larger.